# How to read from tf.data.Iterator both sequentially and randomly in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset

I have build my `tfrecords` database in tensorflow. Now I would like to read records such that the starting point is some random value, say between 10 and 2000, then read sequentially a number of records, say between 100 and 200. How to do that using `tf.data.iterator` or any alternative in tensorflow.

Any help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`tf.data.Dataset.take`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#take) and [`tf.data.Dataset.skip`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#skip) for this.

For example, construct your `tf.data.Dataset` object as follows:

```
starting_point = tf.random_uniform(shape=[], dtype=tf.int64, minval=10, maxval=2000)
num_records = tf.random_uniform(shape=[], dtype=tf.int64, minval=100, maxval=200)

ds = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(...).skip(starting_point).take(num_records)
```

And then you can construct an iterator and the "next value" tensor like any dataset. For example:

```
itr = ds.make_one_shot_iterator()
(x, y) = itr.get_next()
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: when trying to print out the next value along with the `starting_point` and the `num_records`, I just figured out that on every call, the `starting_point` and the `num_records` variables are re-evaluated. `print(sess.run([itr.get_next(), starting_point, num_records]))`. How to prevent this behavior? I am asking since this may slow down the training process.

Comment: that was just solved through:

`ds = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(...).skip(starting_point).take(num_records).batch(num_records)`

Comment: Note that in the answer above `starting_point` and `num_records` will be re-evaluated whenever the `itr` operation is, i.e., each time the iterator is created.

If you want to fix those, then you can set `starting_point` and `num_records` statically, for example, by setting them using `np.random`.